# Laravel Relationship "Belongs to" not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Just wanted to add relationships between models
There is a model

```php
class FrontSectionData extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function frontSection()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FrontSection::class, 'front_section_id');
    }
}
```

There is a migration

```php
class CreateFrontSectionDataTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('front_section_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('front_section_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('front_sections');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('front_section_data');
    }
}
```

Just wanted to add relationships between models

[image: How it looks in PMA]

```
public function t1()
{
 
    $t = FrontSectionData::all()->first();

    dd($t, $t->frontSection);
}
```

[image: object dump]

I tried to change the fields in the database, nothing helped. Returns only null

Comment: Could you show how you are saving the data? Just to make sure you're paying the kids in the bank

Comment: @VitorBellini: "paying the kids in the bank"?

Comment: @VitorBellini Just via phpmyadmin

Comment: Google translator gave a wrong translation.
In this case, it would be to verify if the data actually exists in the database, with the correct FKs

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default I think this is what you need

Comment: @N.Hamelink Now everything is working, but I think that was the reason, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add a fillable property to your model, and add the necessary fields to it, because these fields will be considered when the user inserts or updates the data.

The model should look like this:

```
class FrontSectionData extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
       'front_section_id',
       'description'
    ];

    public function frontSection()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(FrontSection::class, 'front_section_id');
    }
}
```

After that, you should add a relationshop to FrontSection also. Probably, FrontSection has one FrontSectionData, so this relationship should look like this:

```
public function data()
{
   return $this->hasOne(FrontSectionData::class);
}
```

So, when you create FrontSection, you can alo create it's data. Here is some example(you should have attributes for section and for it's data before creating):

```
// $sectionAttributes and $sectionDataAttributes, for example
$newSection = FrontSection::create($sectionAttributes);
$newSectionData = $newSection->data()->create($sectionDataAttributes);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, your solution also worked, like mine after restarting the computer, but what is the reason for this behavior is still not known